# Combo google chart with php from mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, json, charts, datatable

I'm requiring your advices on this project for which I'm trying to feed a "combo" google chart like this one with php from a MS SQL Server database.
[image: Chart view template]

I have built the following view which provides me with the relevant data. I'll have later to create a serie of these charts for each project (identified via 'ProjectUniqueId').

[image: Table view template]

From all the documentation I got so far, I understand that I have to programmatically build the following dataTable

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Week', 'Hrs VSE', 'Hrs PII', 'Hrs VDG', 'Hrs PIA', 'Hrs TCIS', 'Forecast'  ],
      ['2013-W20',  165,          938,         522,         998,        450,          614.6],
      ['2013-W21',  135,          1120,        599,         1268,       288,          682],
      ['2013-W22',  157,          1167,        587,         807,        397,          1200],
      ['2013-W23',  139,          1110,        615,         968,        215,          2000],
      ['2013-W24',  136,          691,         629,         1026,       366,          569.5]
    ]);
```

As part of this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    //Raw data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Week', 'Hrs VSE', 'Hrs PII', 'Hrs VDG', 'Hrs PIA', 'Hrs TCIS', 'Forecast'  ],
      ['2013-W20',  165,          938,         522,         998,        450,          614.6],
      ['2013-W21',  135,          1120,        599,         1268,       288,          682],
      ['2013-W22',  157,          1167,        587,         807,        397,          1200],
      ['2013-W23',  139,          1110,        615,         968,        215,          2000],
      ['2013-W24',  136,          691,         629,         1026,       366,          569.5]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Actuals vs Forecast VLU Project per Cost-Center',
      vAxis: {title: ""},
      //Horizontal axis text vertical
      hAxis: {title: "", slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:90},
      seriesType: "bars",
      series: {5: {type: "line"}},
      isStacked: true
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

I first tried to build the dataTable (which I understand as an "assembly" of arrays), manually by

1) Building an array of "column headers" (CcName)

2) Building an array of "row headers" (WeekValue)

3) Querying each individual value for (HoursValue) a specific WeekValue,CcName
...

Finally I never really managed to build the required array and then found documentation on JSON and how it could help but didn't manage to implement it in my code.

```
<?php

$myServer = "XXXXXX";
$myUser = "reportuser";
$myPass = "";
$myDB = "HOURS"; 

//Connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//Select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//Declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT CcName, WeekValue, SUM(HoursValue) AS HoursValue FROM viewFunctionalHoursKpi WHERE Approval='Actuals' AND ProjectUniqueId=1286 GROUP BY CcName, WeekValue";

//Execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query)
  or die('An error occured: ' . mysql_error());

$resultArray = array();

while ($record = mssql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    //Fill array
    $resultArray[] = $record;
  }                    

//Output in JSON format
echo json_encode($resultArray);

//Free result set memory
mssql_free_result($result);

//Close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

What would you guys advice? I'm definitely open to change the format of the data by changing the current view I've got in MS SQL Server, but the hardest bit to me is how to transport the data I get from php to this js dataTable (if this is the way to do it).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you have to use google charts for this?

Comment: Hi Dagon, I browsed the web quite a lot to try to find something free that would allow me to create this kind of charts (combo stacked bars + line(s)) and googlecharts API seemed to do the job with simple code. What do you have in mind?

Comment: i was going to suggest http://phpchart.net/ but rereading it im not sure if the charting is the issue

Comment: I just checked phpchart.net but their lite version doesn't seem to do much :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have output that same chart with this as my data for the google charts (rewritten for use as an example) :

```
<?php

    //this would be the output of your sql statement
    $resultArray = array(array("this"=>5, "is" =>3, "a"=>4, "test"=>1),
            array("this"=>25, "is" =>23, "a"=>42, "test"=>12),
            array("this"=>50, "is" =>30, "a"=>40, "test"=>10));


    //we find all the keys to use as "headers"
    $keys = array_keys($resultArray[0]);

    //loop through each key adding the needed marks
    $tempData = '';
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $tempData .= "'$key',";
    }

    //this removes the last comma (though you might not need to)
    $data ="[".rtrim($tempData,',')."], \n";

    //more looping, marking and comma removal
    //just through your whole list of results
    foreach($resultArray as $r){
        $tempData = '';
        foreach($r as $val){
            $tempData .= "'$val',";
        }
        $data .= "[".rtrim($tempData,',')."], \n";
    }
    $data = "[".rtrim($data,", \n")."]";

    //echo result
    echo $data;

?>
```

Hope that works for you